# Using sharepoint designer with sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I was wondering if anyone can help me out. Here is the situation.

I want to develop a sharepoint master file, for that i need sharepoint designer and for that i would need sharepoint server & windows servver. I dont want to install & configure the whole stack just for that.

Is it possible that i get a sharepoint online account for $5 or $8 and then download the free available sharepoint 2013 designer and deploy and test things with this combination?

Your quick help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have sharepoint online account, you won't be just able to connect using sharepoint designer.

**You will need to enable scripting.**

I was able to do it using Sharepoint online management shell. 
You will need to

1. install it,
2. you should login through shell to your site admin url.
3. so if you site is abc.sharepoint.com, you will use abc-admin.sharepoint.com using this command

   Connect-SPOService -Url https://abc-admin.sharepoint.com/ -credential account@abc.sharepoint.com
4. Once done do this

   Set-SPOsite https://abc.sharepoint.com/ -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0`code`

You are now ready, just open the site in your sharepoint designer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need SharePoint server. You need SharePoint online account and SharePoint designer.
And then you can create master page,display templates, page layouts, etc. And finally you can create design package which can distributed as you want.

Comment: Ok so once i have sharepoint online account, i would be able to connect my desktop sharepoint designer to sharepoint online account? Can you please guide me towards any reference for handling this? Or does the online version already has some tool to do that, like sort of online sharepoint designer?

Comment: When your tenant will be created, main private site collection will be created for you. Something like this: https://SOMENAME.sharepoint.com Then you can just open SharePoint designer on your desktop -> Open site -> enter your site URL -> you enter login and password -> and you are ready to go.  I wrote already a few things about branding in SharePoint online http://bit.ly/1hDcR8W

Comment: Thanks buddy, will try that

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 supports the design of a master page in HTML only, and that will be converted to a proper .master file, so you don't really need a SharePoint installation to design (but you will probably need SharePoint for for final testing).

The format is basic HTML and the SharePoint controls will be rendered inside special markup, like below:

```
<div id="TurnOnAnimation" style="display:none;" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
        <a id="linkTurnOnAnimation" data-accessibility-nocheck="true" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="ToggleAnimationStatus();return false;">
            <!--SPM:<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="&#60;%$Resources:wss,master_enableanimation%&#62;" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/>-->
        </a>
 </div>
```

The  markup represent SharePoint controls, and you can build alter the HTML around the controls.

I created a dump for you [here](http://pastebin.com/qKJ0Lj6y) of the default SharePoint masterpage file (seattle.master).